# Get a substring from a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have many strings in this format:

```
fdg.sdfg.234fdsa.dsf_1.2.5.62.xml
23432ssdfsa_sadfsd_1.2.7.6.xml
3.3.3asdf_ddd_1.2.1.doc
```

I would like to get only the number
from: `fdg.sdfg.234fdsa.dsf_1.2.5.62.xml` to get: `1.2.5.62`
from: `f23432ssdfsa_sadfsd_1.2.7.6.xml` to get: `1.2.7.6`
from: `f3.3.3asdf_ddd_1.2.1.doc` to get: `1.2.1`
etc

This code works:

```
string test = "4534534ghgggg_1.1.3.4.xml";
int to = test.LastIndexOf('.');
int from = test.LastIndexOf('_') + 1;
Console.WriteLine(test.Substring(from,to - from));
```

But I want to know how can I do it with regex. Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, if the format is fixed so that you can always use _ for the start and the last . for the end, just use Substring.  It's much easier for the majority of devs to read and maintain than a Regex (yes, Regexes aren't impossible to read, but a lot of devs can't).

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to work as long as the numbers you are looking for are preceded by "_".

**Edited - This is the final working result**

```
        // fdg.sdfg.234fdsa.dsf_1.2.5.62.xml 
        // 23432ssdfsa_sadfsd_1.2.7.6.xml
        // 3.3.3asdf_ddd_1.2.1.doc

        string source = "fdg.sdfg.234fdsa.dsf_1.2.5.62.xml";
         var match = Regex.Match(source, @"_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*").ToString().Replace("_", "");
        Console.WriteLine(match);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: be careful: `.` means *any symbol* in regular expression, so `_[0-9].[0-9]` will macth, say `_1x2`

Comment: var match = Regex.Match(source, @"_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9])*").ToString().Replace("_", "");

Comment: Another problem: `_1.2.5.62.` *fails* to match: it should be `(\.[0-9]+)*` in the pattern (please, notice `+`)

Comment: Sorry, accidently removed a "+". Here is the line again. var match = Regex.Match(source, @"_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*").ToString().Replace("_", "");

Comment: I'm sorry, I've copied wrong (occasionaly dropped the last `*`)

Comment: The only thing I'd note: the value is at the end of the string, right before the extension. Use `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` so that the string was parsed from right to left, that will fetch the right match and faster. And of course, get the Match object, and only use `.ToString()` after checking `match.Success` property.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's elaborate the *rules* (*number* is not you want to get) for the match:

- starts with '_' (not included in match)
- contains digits and dots (dots are not duplcated).
- no leading and no trailing dots are allowed
- has at least one digit as well as at least one dot
- ends with '.' (not included in match)

then implement a pattern:

```
 (?<=_)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+(?=\.)
```

if the *number* in the question is, in fact, some kind of version you may want to restict number of its parts, e.g.

```
 (?<=_)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){1,3}(?=\.[^0-9])
```

which means that only 2 to 4 parts versions (`_d.d.`, `_d.d.d.` and `_d.d.d.d.`) are accepted. E.g. input `_1.2.15.` will be accepted (3 parts: `1`, `2` and `15`) when `_1.2.3.4.5.` will be rejected (5 parts)

finally, use regular expressions:

```
  string source = ...
  string pattern = @"(?<=_)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+(?=\.)";

  // If there are many matches, let's take the last one
  string lastMatch = Regex.Matches(pattern, source)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .LastOrDefault();

  Console.Write(lastMatch);
```

However, if format is *fixed* then *regular expression* (and *Linq*) is overshoot. `LastIndex` + `Substring` is a better choice.

Comment: You have a typo in the code: `string pattern = @"?<=_)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+(?=\.)";` must be `string pattern = @"(?<=_)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+(?=\.)";`. You tend to overuse unanchored lookbehinds - I'd rather use capturing groups (I know checking one `_` is no big deal, but in general, they are costly).

Answer (score 1):

You already got all your answers.
I have not practised for the last 6 months and have almost all forgotten.
Anyway there are plenty of web sites ( look for regex tester in your favorite search engine ) that helps you with regex. I do not know if I can mention one more than the other but here are some snapshots of one example ( I am not the latest expert in regex so I hope I did not write something too wrong).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So now you can test all the answers and advices that have been brought to you.
.

Comment: You have chosen the wrong tool to understand .NET regexes: regex101 does not support .NET regex patterns. E.g. `\w` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but is identical to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`. `\d` matches Arabic, Hindi and other digits. Use Ultrapico Expresso to see what .NET subpatterns mean.

Comment: Thanks for reminding this pitfall and quoting a more adequate tool